# Oracle SQL: most efficient way to perform filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, inner-join, where-clause

As I start writing SQL queries on big tables, I wonder which one is the most efficient. To me they all look the same. Looking for an explanation of how SQL will decompose and execute these queries as well

Option 1:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where a.column in (select filter from table_b)
```

Option 2:

```
select a.*
from table_a a, table_b b
where a.column=b.filter
```

Option 3:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on a.column=b.filter
```

Comment: check exec. plan and you will see that it's the same for all three statements. If not, you have a problem somewhere.

Comment: @ibre5041 . . . The execution plan should not be the same for the three statements, because the first does something different from the other two.

Comment: SQL declarative language. Therefore if two statements have the same "meaning" then they also should have the same exec. plan. If you added constraints to the 1st case, then the exec plan would be the same. For example try to add unique, not NULL to filter column. But I understand that generally the 1st case is different - cardinality differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest versions of Oracle, the **optimizer** is smart enough to do its job. So it won't matter and both of your queries would be internally optimized to do the task efficiently. Optimizer might do a **query re-write** and opt an **efficient execution plan**.

Let's understand this with a small example of `EMP` and `DEPT` table.

**Query 1 :**

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select a.*
  3  from emp a
  4  WHERE A.deptno IN (SELECT deptno FROM dept);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."DEPTNO" IS NOT NULL)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Query 2 :**

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  SELECT A.*
  3  FROM emp A, dept b
  4  where a.deptno=b.deptno;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."DEPTNO" IS NOT NULL)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Query 3 :**

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select a.*
  3  from emp a
  4  INNER JOIN dept b
  5  ON A.deptno=b.deptno;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."DEPTNO" IS NOT NULL)

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, the optimizer chose the most efficient execution plan irrespective of the way you wrote the queries differently. Unless you force the optimizer to chose a different plan using hints etc. You would always see there are executed using the same plan.

Comment: Btw, those queries might return different results when the join is 1-n instead of n-1, simply swap `emp` and `dept` in the subquery. Is the plan still the same in this case after adding `DISTINCT`? And for EXISTS, too?

Comment: In your case the `DEPT` table is completely excluded from exec. plan. Maybe due to FK  on deptno?

Comment: An execution plan depends of many parameters (volume, indexes, database configuration). so, there is no one unique truth ... you have to experiment by yourselves and choose the solution that fit to your specific needs. Read the books from Tom Kyte.